# How to use options for both command line and hierarchical config file with Boost Program_Options

Tags: c++, boost, config, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

Imagine I have a program that takes the following command-line option:

`$ prog1 --foo 1`

I also have a configuration file that is in this hierarchical format, with the `foo` parameter within the `prog1` scope:

```
[prog1]
foo = 42
```

My understanding of Boost::program_options is that the command-line option is defined similar to:

```
description.add_options()
    ("foo", "Set foo value");
```

However I want the value in the config file to be a default value (as an outcome of calling `store()` twice, first with the command-line description, then the config file description), able to be overriden by the command-line option, but I believe the config file option has to be declared as:

```
description.add_options()
    ("prog1.foo", "Set foo value");
```

Note the use of `prog1.foo` here, especially the `prog1.` prefix.

So my question is, if you use hierarchical config-file options, how do you associate these with command line options? I.e. how do I make `--foo` and `prog1.foo` represent the same configuration value in the Storage object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned enough to answer my own question. Hopefully this will help someone one day, because the Boost::Program_Options documentation does not cover this.

If you create a hierarchical config option like this (this *is* documented):

```
    config_only_opts.add_options()
        ("section.option", po::bool_switch(), "Some option");
```

And pass it to both `parse_command_line()` and `parse_config_file()`.

Then the config file would look like this:

```
[section]
option=1
```

And the command-line option would look like this (this is *not* documented):

```
--section.option
```

So the hierarchical options translate into dotted command-line options. Therefore I'd expect this:

```
[one.two]
three=4
```

To be equivalant to the following config option:

```
--one.two.three=4
```

Defaults that are applied to the command-line or config file options apply in the way you'd expect, depending on the order that `store()` is called.

If you want to associate an arbitrary command-line option, such as `--foo`, with a hierarchical (or flat) config file value like `bar.baz`, then you can register the former with `parse_command_line()` and the latter with `parse_config_file()`, but reference the *same* storage variable for each:

```
    bool foo;

    po::options_description cmdline_opts;
    cmdline_only_opts.add_options()
        ("foo", po::value<bool>(&foo), "Foo")
        ;

    po::options_description config_file_opts;
    config_only_opts.add_options()
        ("bar.baz", po::value<bool>(&foo))
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, cmdline_opts), vm);
    po::store(po::parse_config_file("config.file", config_file_opts, true /* allow unregistered */), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
```

Now you can use `--foo` or

```
[bar]
baz=X
```

to set the variable `foo`. The only caveat to be careful about is that you can no longer use `vm[XXX].as<T>()` where "XXX" is "foo" or "bar.baz" to access the value - just use the referenced storage variable instead.